# dotnet watch command can't run and find frameworks even with sdk and runtime installed

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linux, .net-core

I'm trying to run a C# project with dotnet, but when I run `dotnet watch run` it complains about not having found any frameworks, not sure what that means though as I have installed the runtime and SDK (with yay).

This is my output when I ran that command:

```bash
You must install or update .NET to run this application.

App: /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.100/DotnetTools/dotnet-watch/8.0.100-rtm.23551.6/tools/net8.0/any/dotnet-watch.dll
Architecture: x64
Framework: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '8.0.0' (x64)
.NET location: /usr/share/dotnet/

No frameworks were found.

Learn more:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed

To install missing framework, download:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.AspNetCore.App&framework_version=8.0.0&arch=x64&rid=arch-x64&os=arch
```

However this is my output when I run things like `dotnet --info`

```bash
.NET SDK:
 Version:           8.0.100
 Commit:            57efcf1350
 Workload version:  8.0.100-manifests.2d90560f

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     arch
 OS Version:  
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         arch-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.100/

.NET workloads installed:
 Workload version: 8.0.100-manifests.2d90560f
There are no installed workloads to display.

Host:
  Version:      8.0.0
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       5535e31a71

.NET SDKs installed:
  7.0.114 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
  8.0.100 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.14 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 8.0.0 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Other architectures found:
  None

Environment variables:
  DOTNET_ROOT       [/usr/share/dotnet/]

global.json file:
  Not found

Learn more:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/info

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/download
```

Not only do I have dotnet correctly (as far I can see) installed, but I also can run `dotnet run` and `dotnet publish` with no problem at all.

Do you guys have any idea what might be missing?

Comment: Yuu have the net core frameworks installed but as the error tells you you miss the AspNetCore framework.

Comment: Reread the last two lines of the output of `dotnet watch run` you also posted here.

Comment: Ok, I was expecting dotnet sdk would have everything but aspnet is a separate thing. Thank you